# node js console and endpoint returning object but cannot fetch as json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using an NLP sentiment analysis API for a project for and online course.  I think I'm close but I can't finish the final step.  Currently when I send the URL to be analyzed by the API call I get the returned object in the server console and then I send the data to the route /sentiment.  Then I have a function where I'm trying to fetch the data from /sentiment and update the page to show the results.  #hen I try to fetch the data from /sentiment I get an empty object and my page is updated with undefineds.  When I go to /sentiment I can see all the data but the fetch isn't working.  I think these are the relevant parts of my code:

index.js (server side):

```
var path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const mockAPIResponse = require('./mockAPI.js');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express()
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static('dist'))

dotenv.config();
console.log(`Your API key is ${process.env.API_ID}`);

console.log(__dirname)

projectData = {};

url = {};

const AYLIENTextAPI = require('aylien_textapi');

let textapi = new AYLIENTextAPI({
    application_id: process.env.API_ID,
    application_key: process.env.API_KEY,
})


let apiCall = async (url) => {
    textapi.sentiment({
        'url': url
    }, function(error, response) {
        if (error === null) {
            JSON.stringify(response);
            projectData = response;
            console.log(projectData);
        }else{
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
};

app.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        console.log(process.env);
        res.sendFile('dist/index.html', { root: __dirname + '/,'})
    })
    .post(getSentiment);

function getSentiment(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    projectData = req.body;
    console.log(projectData);
    res.status(200).send(projectData);
};

const port = 8000;

// designates what port the app will listen to for incoming requests
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Example app listening on ${port}`)
})

app.get('/sentiment', getData);

function getData(req, res){
    JSON.stringify({projectData});
    res.status(200).send(projectData)
    console.log(projectData)
};

app.post('/postURL', getURL);

function getURL(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    url = req.body.data;
    console.log(url)
    apiCall(url)
}
```

formHandler.js:

```
import { postURL } from "./postURL"
import { updateUI } from "./updateUI"

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    // check what text was put into the form field
    let url = document.getElementById('URL').value
    postURL('/postURL', url)
    updateUI();
};

export { handleSubmit }
```

updateUI.js:

```
const updateUI = async () =>{
    const res = await fetch('/sentiment');
    try {
        const allData = await res.json();
        console.log(allData)
        document.getElementById("polarity").innerHTML = allData.polarity;
        document.getElementById("polarityConfidence").innerHTML = allData.polarity_confidence;
        document.getElementById("subjectivity").innerHTML = allData.subjectivity;
        document.getElementById("subjectivityConfidence").innerHTML = allData.subjectivity_confidence;
        return allData
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};

export { updateUI }
```

I don't know why I see all the data on the server side and at /sentiment but only get an empty object when I try to fetch it in the updateUI function.  Any help would be really, really appreciated.

Thanks alot,
Michael

Comment: This does nothing -> `JSON.stringify({projectData});`  try -> `res.status(200).json(projectData)`

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide full path to server like

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/sentiment');
```

Or try moving

```
app.get('/sentiment', getData);
```

Above

```
app.route('/')
```

Update

```
const allData = await res.json(); // problem is here
```

try

```
 console.log(res.data); // here you will see what you are getting.
 const allData = await res.data; // You might will be having the response here
```

---

You this might be helpful.

```
const updateUI = async () =>{
    const res = await fetch('/sentiment');
    try {
        const allData = res.data; // here
        console.log(allData)
        document.getElementById("polarity").innerHTML = allData.polarity;
        document.getElementById("polarityConfidence").innerHTML = allData.polarity_confidence;
        document.getElementById("subjectivity").innerHTML = allData.subjectivity;
        document.getElementById("subjectivityConfidence").innerHTML = allData.subjectivity_confidence;
        return allData
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};

export { updateUI }
```

Comment: neither of those solutions worked.  any other ideas?

Comment: @MichaelWycklendt What are You getting in console after running `console.log(projectData)` ? in getData function

Comment: i'm getting all the data wrapped in {}

Comment: I changed const allData = await res.json(); to const allData = await JSON.parse(res.data) and const allData = JSON.parse(res.data) and got the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>).  Any idea why?

Comment: when I add console.log(res) I get Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:8000/sentiment", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} in the console

Comment: @MichaelWycklendt then you can `const allData = await res.data` and please log first and see what you need or share the `console.log(res)`

Comment: @MichaelWycklendt See the problem is what you are finding is in `res.data` please `console.log(res.data)`   `const allData = await res.data` then `console.log(allData)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208499/discussion-between-michael-wycklendt-and-rajan-lagah).

Comment: i did a console log of res.data and i got this:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:8000/sentiment", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:8000/sentiment"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

Answer (score -2):

### `JSON.stringify` + `res.send` = Content-Type "text/html"

Your client app cannot deserialise it to JSON.
Your issue is that you are `JSON.stringify`-ing it and sending it via `res.send` from the server.

This combination sets the wrong Content-Type header.

Read the Express API doc for [`res.send`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send):

> When the parameter is a String, the method sets the Content-Type to “text/html”:

So you can see it in your browser fine, because the browser is rendering text, but the client app can't deserialise it with `res.json()` because the content-type is not set correctly from the server.

```
function getData(req, res){
    JSON.stringify({projectData});
    res.status(200).send(projectData) <- "text/html"
    console.log(projectData)
};
```

It needs to be set to `application/json`.

### Here is what you need to do

1. Change your endpoint to `sendJson`
2. Don't `JSON.stringify` it. Send the object and let Express serialise it.

```
function getData(req, res){
    // JSON.stringify({projectData}); <- don't stringify it
    res.sendJson(projectData) // <- use sendJSON
    console.log(projectData)
};
```

Read the Express API doc for [`res.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json):

> Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().

Comment: He is not assigning `JSON.stringify({projectData})` to something so might not be helpful :-).

Comment: Have a look at the `getData` method in his server. He is stringifying the JSON, then sending the stringified json as plaintext. And on the client using `res.json()`. My hypothesis is he can see it in his browser, but the json serialization is not working for the `res.json()` in the client app, maybe because of content-type header.